# WinForms listbox keydown event won't fire

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, keydown, eventtrigger

I am trying to make a WinForm ListBox in which you can loop trough using the arrow keys. I also have two buttons on which you can click to go up and down the list. The buttons do produce the desired effect. The problem is that the ListBox's keyDown event is never triggered

```
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (this.clipboardHistoryList.Items.Count > 0)
            this.clipboardHistoryList.SetSelected(0, true);
        clipboardHistoryList.Select();
    }

   private void goUpButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        goUpList();
    }

    private void goDownButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        goDownList();
    }

    private void goDownList()
    {
        if (clipboardHistoryList.SelectedIndex == clipboardHistoryList.Items.Count - 1)
        {
            clipboardHistoryList.SetSelected(0, true);
        }
        else
        {
            clipboardHistoryList.SetSelected(clipboardHistoryList.SelectedIndex + 1, true);
        }
    }

    private void goUpList()
    {
        if (clipboardHistoryList.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            clipboardHistoryList.SetSelected(clipboardHistoryList.Items.Count - 1, true);
        }
        else
        {
            int l_currentlySelected = clipboardHistoryList.SelectedIndex;
            clipboardHistoryList.SetSelected(l_currentlySelected - 1, true);
        }
    }

    private void clipboardHistoryList_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)         //Brekpoint is never reached
        {
            goUpList();
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        {
            goDownList();
        }
    }
```

I have put the MainForm's keypreview proprety to true.

The arrow keys do work by default on a listbox but they won't let you go from last to first element if you press the down arrow on the last element --hopes this makes sense.

**EDIT**
I have seen on [Microsoft's documentation](http://Perform%20special%20input%20or%20navigation%20handling%20on%20a%20control.%20For%20example,%20you%20want%20the%20use%20of%20arrow%20keys%20in%20your%20list%20control%20to%20change%20the%20selected%20item.%09Override%20ProcessDialogKey) that I need to override the `ProcessDialogKey` method but I am not exactly sure of what I need to do.

> Perform special input or navigation handling on a control. For example, you want the use of arrow keys in your list control to change the selected item.  Override ProcessDialogKey

Is there already a built-in way to enable this behaviour?

What did I miss?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you 100% certain that your ListBox is actually wired into your event handler?  When I create a form with a ListBox on it, it's correctly firing the KeyDown event every time I use the arrow keys.  I'd suggest looking in the Designer.cs file for your Form, and verifying that you can find a line similar to this where it actually wires into the event: this.listBox1.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.listBox1_KeyDown);

Comment: The ListBox either doesn't have the focus or you don't have the event wired.  `I have put the MainForm's keydown proprety to true.`  Did you mean KeyPreview?

Comment: @JoeIrby I don't see any line like that in my Form1.Designer.cs file. I updated the question with the content of this file.

Comment: @LarsTech I did mean keypreview

Comment: You have to wire your events.  Notice how your Buttons have events wired up in the designer, but your ListBox does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From looking at the code in your Designer.cs file, it doesn't look like you've actually got your clipboardHistoryList control wired into your clipboardHistoryList_KeyDown event handler.  You can do that through the "Events" subtab of the Properties window in your visual studio form designer (look for the little lightning bolt icon) and wire up the event through the designer that way, or alternatively you can do it in code:

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    if (this.clipboardHistoryList.Items.Count > 0)
        this.clipboardHistoryList.SetSelected(0, true);
    clipboardHistoryList.Select();

    clipboardHistoryList.KeyDown += clipboardHistoryList_KeyDown;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, now the event is being triggered correctly! But I face an other problem now... Every time I press an arrow, the cursor moves of two lines as if the keydown event was handled by my method AND by the default component's method. How can I fix this?

Comment: You need to add e.handled = true; to your new event handler.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that fixed it!

Comment: @Gaboik1 it is in fact possible to accidentally wire into an event twice, in which case it would get called twice each time, as you're experiencing.  If you added my line of code to your MainForm() constructor, *AND* you also wired into the event through the designer, then this might be what happened.  You only need to do one or the other (your choice), not both.

Comment: @JoeIrby Hm it's funny because I only wired it into the Designer file and it still was called twice. Setting the handled attribute of the event to true solved it tho

Comment: @joeIrby  The listbox has built in handling just as the textbox does. If you don't tell windows that you handled it, it will pass it on to the base control.

Comment: Strange, I don't get that same behavior in my simple test case; by wiring into the event through the designer, and doing nothing else, it still only fires the event once for me.  Weird.  Well, whatever - what I suggested obviously wasn't the problem, lol.  Glad you got it working with e.Handled!